# Draw multiple lines in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

In Swift 4, with the Xcode IDE, I can easily draw a circle with the following:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(
    x: 100,
    y: 100),
    radius: 50,
    startAngle: CGFloat(0),
    endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2),
    clockwise: true)

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
```

However, I want to draw a line from point A to point B, not draw a circle.  I can draw a line by following the example code here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sJxtzTo8W0

In order for the line to appear the same way that it does in the example, I need to change the view in the main storyboard.

- Does this mean that I can only have 1 type of custom class in my entire project that is viewable at any given time?
- Can I make the lines viewable by default, regardless of the specific storyboard view?
- Why does the circle render without me needing to define a class object, but the line requires me to define a class object?
- Is there a way to simply draw a line on the fly, in the same way that I can draw a circle on the fly?

Comment: Not important and not related, but you don’t need all those `CGFloat` references when defining your circle, e.g. it’s just `let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), radius: 50, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)`

Comment: "Can I make the lines viewable by default” ... I don’t understand that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to simply draw a line on the fly, in the same way that I can draw a circle on the fly?

Sure, just create a `UIBezierPath` with `addLine(to:)` and then use the following `path` in your `CAShapeLayer`, just like you did for the circle in your example:

```
let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 5)

let linePath = UIBezierPath()
linePath.move(to: startPoint)
linePath.addLine(to: endPoint)

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = linePath.cgPath

shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2

view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

> Why does the circle render without me needing to define a class object, but the line requires me to define a class object?

The line doesn’t require you to define class object. It’s just another way of doing it and you can do both lines and circles (and whatever other types of shapes you want) using either the `CAShapeLayer` technique or the `UIView` subclass technique. They both work fine.

A `UIView` subclass approach, you first define your class:

```
class LineView: UIView {

    var startPoint: CGPoint? { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    var endPoint: CGPoint?   { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let startPoint = startPoint, let endPoint = endPoint else { return }

        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: startPoint)
        linePath.addLine(to: endPoint)
        linePath.lineWidth = 2

        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        linePath.stroke()
    }
}
```

And then instantiate one and add it to your view hierarchy:

```
let lineView = LineView()
lineView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
lineView.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
lineView.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 5)
view.addSubview(lineView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    lineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
    lineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
    lineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
    lineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10)
])
```

> Does this mean that I can only have 1 type of custom class in my entire project that is viewable at any given time?

Just like you can add whatever shapelayers you want, you can add your own custom `UIView` subclasses and add however many you want. So you could theoretically have a couple of subclass types, one for different types of shapes (circles, lines, rounded rectangles, whatever) and instantiate them and add them as subviews to whatever view on whatever scene you wanted.

Comment: When i use your provided code, the line is not drawn on the screen.  Can you provide the full code please?

Comment: How can I instantiate as a subview?

Comment: @ColinHancey - To draw the line, you create a shape layer, set its `path`, and then `addSublayer`, just like you did with the `circlePath` example in your question. But I provided a little more code.

Comment: @ColinHancey - And to instantiate a subview, just create subclass instance (e.g. `LineView()` will instantiate a `LineView` object) and then to see it, just configure it and add it to your view hierarchy with `addSubview`. I’ve added an example of how to do that, above, too.